# Erro estranho undefined no visual

Tags: php, jquery

Quando acesso a `index.php` do meu site mostra um `undefined` deste tipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando vou no código fonte o texto está escrito corretamente lá:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sinceramente eu nunca vi um erro desse.

Comment: Primeiro erro: Usar Windows XP rsrs (brincadeira :p)... cara, será que não tem algum script alterando o texto desses elementos? Poste na pergunta a parte do código envolvida na questão em vez de print de código. Se tiver algum script jQuery que esteja relacionado a isso, poste tb na pergunta para podermos dar uma analisada.

Comment: DXD HMMMMM DXDZINHOOOOOOO

Answer (score -2):

ERA UM SCRIPT.JS EU USEI ESSE SCRIPT EM 20 PAGINAS PHP ... EM ALGUM DELES EU ESCREVI ALGUMA COISA IGUAL ACHO Q DEVE SER UMA CLASSE, COLOQUEI O SCRIPT SOMENTE NA INDEX.PHP E DEU CERTO

RECADINHO PRA MENINADA PROGRAMADOR NUNCA SAIA USANDO APENAS 1 ARQUIVO JS PRA VARIOS PHP !

ABRAÇOS, TOU FAZENDO SITE DO 0 E TO ARREPENDIDO!